# Is there a work-around for SetOptions having no ImageSize option?

Tags: graphics, front-end

I'd like to set the output cell size to a specified height and width or to
full screen as F12 does.

```
data = Reverse[Sort[RandomReal[1, 5]]];
Module[{t = 0, len = Length[data], sum = Total[data]}, 
 Graphics[Table[{Hue[i/len], EdgeForm[Opacity[.8]], 
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {t, t += 2 Pi data[[i]]/sum}]}, {i, len}]]]

SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, Cell]
SetOptions[NotebookSelection[EvaluationNotebook[]], Background -> Red,
  TextAlignment -> Center]
```

Comment: @kglr - Please take a look at this again.

Comment: Youvan, play with the numbers in `SetOptions[NotebookSelection[EvaluationNotebook[]], Background -> Red,
  TextAlignment -> Center, CellSize -> {100, 200}, 
 CellMargins -> {{300, 0}, {5, 5}}, PageWidth -> 800, CellLabel -> ""]` to see if you get what you need.

Comment: kglr, With F12 and a 1000 x 1000 image, this works: CellSize -> {1500, 
  1200}, CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {5, 5}}, PageWidth -> 1920